# Is it possible to make an MP4 file without video using FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I want to remove the video part of an mp4 and only retain the audio but I don't want to convert it to m4a or mp3 or ogg.

I want it to remain as mp4, is this possible using Ffmpeg? And if so, how?

I know that I can get extract just the video (without the audio) into another MP4 but here I want to do the opposite, I want to strip out the video while retaining *only* the audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *negative mapping* to disable a stream (notice a dash in the video stream map option):

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:v -c:a copy audio.mp4
```

Read further in the [Map descrption](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

Comment: Or just `-vn`, IIRC